# Cron service is not executing my script

Tags: cron, centos

I created a shell script that will move and copy some files. My script is working. Everyday I run it manually because cron is not doing its job (I probably did it wrong). My shell file has permissions *777*, all folders, CRON/ROOT is have permissions *777*. I'm running Cent OS 6.7 Final. I want to run this cron everyday at 01:01AM.

My script (pdb.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
/etc/init.d/pdb stop
mv /var/www/html/acesso/ui/root/mtaserver.conf /root/PDB/mods/deathmatch/mtaserver.conf
sleep 2
cp /root/PDB/mods/deathmatch/mtaserver.conf /var/www/html/acesso/ui/root/mtaserver.conf
sleep 2
mv /var/www/html/acesso/ui/root/admintag.lua /root/PDB/mods/deathmatch/resources/[RESOURCES]/022/admintag.lua
sleep 2
cp /root/PDB/mods/deathmatch/resources/[RESOURCES]/022/admintag.lua /var/www/html/acesso/ui/root/admintag.lua
sleep 2
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/acesso/ui/root/ 
/etc/init.d/pdb start
```

crontab -l
[image: Image Link]

crontab -e
[image: Image Link]

Comment: Try putting `/bin/sh` in front of the script location.

Comment: Thanks. Today i will try it.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try putting /bin/sh in front of the script location. – Matt Schuchard